# jquery comobox selected value not rendered

Tags: jquery, select, combobox, render

My problem is this:

I have a jquery combobox element.
When page loads the first option element is showed but when i select other element just not the first one and post the page, it renders back and then some client code runs (jquery) and it set's the value of the combox to be what i want it to be:

```
$("#ddl_Cities").val(_dest); // '_dest' has the value of one of the options
```

The strange thing is that when i debug it i see that

```
$("#ddl_Cities option:selected").text();
$("#ddl_Cities option:selected").val();
$("#ddl_Cities").val();
$("#ddl_Cities")[0].selectedIndex;
```

ALL are showing the text, the value and the index of MY selection ('_dest') and not the first element.
Its like it knows which one was selected but doesn't render it to screen.

Can you figure out what's behind this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

When you post the page, it will reload with default values (first element here), nothing abnormal with this.
I guess what you're debugging happens BEFORE the page reloads, isn't it ?

Comment: I guess you're using a variable, but just in case you don't, shouldn't you write it $("#ddl_Cities").val('_dest') instead of $("#ddl_Cities").val(_dest) ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you don't omit a $(document).ready() for example ? Or that your code is right at the back of your page ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Your code here
});
```